# Stresses in a rotating shaft

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque, stress-strain

I'm studying shafts and I am stuck with a question. The authors that I'm reading from, almost all, use the same initial procedure, something along the lines of using the distortion energy failure theory to compute stresses and then use one of the many failure curves, mod Goodman for example to solve for the diameter. The diameter then becomes a function of
$$d = f(M_a, M_m, T_a, T_m)$$
where the indices $a$ represent alternating and $m$ represent midrange. $M$ stands for bending moment and $T$ stands for torsion. I can completely follow up to this point and understand the train of thought. However, at this point, Shigley for example, states

> For a rotating shaft with constant bending and torsion, the bending stress is completely reversed and torsion is steady.

Then it's stated that the equations for the diameter can be simplified by setting $M_m=0$ and $T_a=0$.

Now I think I understand why the bending stress is reversed, and why we are setting $M_m=0$, but I cannot understand why is torsion steady. Is it not the case that the shaft experiences this sort of torsion stress?

[image: Credit: http://adaptivemap.ma.psu.edu/]

Maybe I have misunderstood how is stress traced? Is stress traced radially or tangentially?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at *a particular piece of material* in the shaft, the torsional stress on that piece of material is "steady" in the sense that it does not change as the shaft rotates. The torsion stress on different pieces of material is different, as your diagram shows.

The bending stress on a particular piece of material changes from tension to compression and back to tension during each rotation of the shaft.